# Operations Research - complementary Slackness and optimal Solution

Tags: matrices, linear-programming

I have to verify the complementary Slackness, but I don't understand what it says and how to do it.

Given: primal LP

$$\begin{align*}\max&\quad c^tx\\\mathrm{s.t.} &\quad Ax=b \\&\quad x\geqslant0\end{align*}$$ and dual LP

$$\begin{align*}\min&\quad b^ty\\\mathrm{s.t.} &\quad A^ty \geqslant c\end{align*}$$
where
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\2&-1&1\end{bmatrix},\; b= \begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix},\;c =\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix},\;y_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},\;y_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Calculate:

1. $\max\{b^t y_1+x^t  (c-A^ty_1) : x\geqslant 0\}$, and
2. $\max\{b^t y_2+x^t  (c-A^ty_2) : x\geqslant0\}$.

What's the connection of the solutions of them and the admissibility of $y_i$?

I calculated them:

1. $\max\{2+x^t(0,-2,-3) : x\geqslant 0\}=\max\{2-2x_2-3x_3 :x\geqslant 0\}$
2. $\max\{1+x^t(-1,1,-3):x\geqslant0\}=\max\{1-x_1+x_2-3x_3:x\geqslant0\}$.

That's my solution, but how can I now verify the Slackness and get the optimal solution pair $(x^*,y^*)$?